# Filled Julia set

Tags: complex-dynamics

How would I find the filled Julia set for $f(z)=z^3$? I know it should be the filled unit circle, but I don't quite understand the math.  This is what I have so far: 
Fixed points
$z^3=z$ so $z=1,-1,0,\infty$
$f'(1)=3>1$--repelling
$f'(-1)=3>1$--repelling
$f'(0)=0<1$--super attracting
$f'(\infty)=0<1$--super attracting

Answer (score 1):

One definition says that the filled Julia set is the set of points that have bounded orbit.

It is clear that $z$ has bounded orbit under $f$ iff $|z|\le1$.

Comment: For this example it is clear, but what about for something like f(z)=z^3-3z?

Comment: @user121955, cubic Julia sets have been studied by Branner and [Hubbard](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hubbard). For a quick picture, [ask WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=julia+set+of+z%5E3-3z). See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/177270/examples-of-cubic-julia-sets.

Comment: @lhf Would you believe that the Julia set of $f(z)=z^3-3z$ is the interval $[-2,2]$! In fact, the dynamics of $f$ on $\mathbb C\setminus [-2,2]$ are semi-conjugate to $g(z)=z^3$ on the exterior of the unit disk via $\varphi(z)=z+1/z$. Of course, finding such a simple Julia set is highly unusual and you are completely correct in pointing out that we should often use a computer to sketch it.